# Return even if more associations than scope asks

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have `Users` and `Languages` tables, joined by `LanguagesUsers`. `LanguagesUsers` stores the `language_id`, `user_id`, and `level`.
`Users` can have unlimited `LanguagesUsers`.

I want to get all users who have any two languages. I have two scopes in my user model:

```
scope :seeking_proficiency_in, ->(language) {
  joins(:languages_users).where("level < 5 and language_id = ?", language)
}
scope :proficient_in, ->(language) {
  joins(:languages_users).where("level > 4 and language_id = ?", language)
}
```

I want to pass two languages, and find users who have both these scopes. The query is like this:

```
@users =
  (User.seeking_proficiency_in(1) && User.proficient_in(2)) ||
  (User.seeking_proficiency_in(2) && User.proficient_in(1))
```

This returns all users who have both languages and the appropriate level of the languages. The issue is that **user that have more than two languages are not included**; only users with exactly the two languages are included.

How can I get all users even if they have more languages than the two given?

UPDATE 
To give more context, this would work, but I feel there is a simple, one-two step version I am not comprehending:

```
learning = User.seeking_proficiency_in(1)
fluent = User.proficient_in(2)
matches = learning & fluent

learning = User.seeking_proficiency_in(2)
fluent = User.proficient_in(1)
second_matches = learning & fluent

all_matches = matches + second_matches
```

Comment: Maybe you don't need to use the scope.  The level filter is irrelevant now.  Just do `User.joins(:languages_users).where(language_id: [1,2])`

Comment: @jvnill thanks for the suggestions - the level needs to be there. The user can't have both languages with the same level. I'm looking for a user with both languages at different levels (see the scope for exact levels for each)

Comment: are you using Rails 5? This is done more easily in Rails 5 than in earlier versions.

Comment: @Toby1Kenobi yes - rails 5.0.1

Answer (score 3):

I thought I wasn't just aware of the additional usage of `&&` and `||` recently added to ActiveRecord.  I think that's your issue there.

`@users` is effectively just `User.proficient_in(2)` because of how `&&` and `||` operators work.  See examples below

```
  >> nil && true                            # nil
  >> true && 1                              # 1
  >> [] && 1                                # 1
  >> User.where(id: 1) && User.where(id: 2) # result will be the result of User.where(id: 2)
```

Since `User.where(...)` queries return an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object, the returned value is not falsy therefore the second part of your code (the one that comes after `||`) is never executed.

In short, you cannot use `&&` and `||` to merge ActiveRecord queries.  Try the following instead

```
 inverse = User.seeking_proficiency_in(2).proficient_in(1)
 @users = User.seeking_proficiency_in(1).proficient_in(2).or(inverse)
```

Comment: I really like this solution and have been playing with it. When I do `User.seeking_proficiency_in(2).proficient_in(1)` it returns an empty array. When I do just `User.seeking_proficiency_in(2)` or `User.proficient_in(1)` It returns hundreds of users. Many of these users are in both arrays. Any thoughts as to why the combined query is returning an empty array? Thanks!

Comment: ahhh I think that's because of the level.  If you look at the sql, you'll see that it's trying to find languages_users records where the level < 5 AND level > 4 which will never be true.  trying to find a way to approach your situation.

Comment: Language 1 needs to be less than level 5, AND language 2 needs to be level 5. Or the inverse can be true. Any suggestions how to pull that? Thank you!

Comment: I updated the original post with more details of the expected outcome. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I can't think of a Rails way to do this other than how you did it.  The only improvement I can think of is using ids for the intersection (use `pluck`) so you are not creating objects unnecessarily.  I've added the sql tag for this question hoping some sql expert shed some light.